# How to run a python while loop until a variable is created?

Tags: python, while-loop

I want a while loop in python to run until a variable is created, like so:

```
while choice doesn't exist:
  do stuff involving choice
end while loop
```

How to do?

Comment: How about initializing with `choice = None`?

Comment: is there a way without initializing, like while choice False or something?

Comment: No when you use `choice` to start the while loop it has to be initialized. But as Tobias said, you can just make it `None` and say `while choice == None:`

Comment: @Gullydwarf: for comparison with `None`, better use the identity operator (`is`).

Comment: Alternatively, you could just use `while not choice:`, which looks vaguely like  doesn't exist.

Comment: How would you `do stuff involving choice` if it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 3):

```
while 'choice' not in locals():
    # your code here
```

But you are doing it the wrong way. You better initialize the variable before the loop like this:

```
choice = None
while choice is None:
    # your code
```

Comment: The first one wouldn't work inside a function if `choice` was defined, but outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of `exists()` in Python (like in other programming languages). We usually use a bool evaluation and initialize the variable in question with a falsish value, like in the following approach:

```
found = False
while not found:
    found = search()
```

`search()` in this case represents your method of choice, which at some point changes the value bound to `found` to a trueish one.

Comment: Well, there is `hasattr`, but I don't think you can use it for module-level variables.

Comment: @tobias_k: there always is a hack, of course. Even in this case, clearly we have a way to inspect the existence of module level names. Because: all names in Python are stored in dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

An almost Pythonic way to do it:

```
def exists(variable):
    try:
        eval(variable)
    except NameError:
        return False
    return True

while not exists('choice'):
    choice = 42

print(choice)
```

I say "almost" because it would be more so to just put the `try/except` in the loop itself:

```
done = False
while not done:
    try:
        # do stuff with choice
        choice = 42
        print(choice)
        done = True
    except NameError:
        pass
```